# App doesn't load on device when not connected to Wifi

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Not sure where to go with this one as I am  not sure if it is code related or something else. I have a working React Native app that works great on the simulator and also on the device when connected to the wifi or plugged into the Mac.

Now I have noticed that when I remove the device and place it on 4G/3G the app does not load and hangs on the loading screen. It may take a number of re-opens of the app before I can get it to run once. Funny thing is that at the minute the app only has the UI built so there are no calls to remote servers etc that may be causing it to hang.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's trying to connect to the packager on your Mac. You'll need to put it in release mode, but you won't be able to reload code with the developer menu that way. Another workaround is to put your phone in airplane mode while it's opening, it will load from a pre-bundle. Are you using an iOS or Android device?

Comment: Thanks for the information, I am using an IOS device.

Answer (score 1):

For iOs, in Xcode you can go `Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme... > Run` & set the `Build Configuration` to `Release`. Then run it on your device & it will be a release build that won't try to connect to your packager, but won't have the sometimes useful developer options at your disposal.

[image]